# Android TextView not showing multiple lines, even though String has newlines

Tags: android, string, textview, newline

My app grabs a webpage using JSoup, and gets text from elements to put into a String. When I print the string normally with `System.out`, it prints on multiple lines.

However when I put the string into a TextView using `setText(myStringname)`, the Text displays but doesn't have more than one line. I have set `android:maxLines` to 16. I use `articleDescs=articleDescs.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+",System.getProperty("line.separator"));` to replace other things with a System new line character.

Lets say my TextView string is `Welcome to the TextView! \nWhat are we doing? \nPrinting new lines!`I want text to show up like

```
Welcome to the TextView!
What are we doing?
Printing new lines!
```

But it shows up ike this:

```
Welcome to the TextView! What are we doing? Printing new lines!
```

How do I make it display the text on multiple lines? I tried looking at other questions but they told my to do `maxLines`, which I did. Thanks

EDIT: TextView XML

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tv_placeholder"
        android:maxLines="16"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

            String pretty=Jsoup.clean(aPrep,"",Whitelist.none().addTags("br","p"),new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(true));
            String articleDescs=Jsoup.clean(pretty,"",Whitelist.none(),new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
            articleDescs=articleDescs.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+","\n");
            System.out.println(articleDescs);
            String articleImgURLs=articleImgURLsArray;
            articleDescs=Jsoup.parse(articleDescs).text();
```

Comment: post textview xml code

Comment: updated my question with the xml code

Comment: [maxLines makes the TextView be at most that many lines tall.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines). The problem may be at your string. show all respective code pls

Comment: @PedroHawk I updated my question

Comment: Have you tried to set a static text, let's say `Row1\nRow2` without the `replaceAll` substitution?

Comment: @j.e.gr No, I can try that now and get back to you

Comment: @j.e.gr It is definitely an issue with my string then, since the static string printed out on multiple lines

Comment: Or with the `replaceAll` code but regexp is not my forte.\